# Django admin import-export, problems with import option

Tags: django, django-admin, django-import-export

I am using the django-import-export via admin, but I have a problem with import option:

When I try to import some data, although doesn't show up any errors, all fields of the entries come white and not with the supposed values.

Anyone have a clue?

Comment: It would probably help to post your model and a sample of the data you're trying to import.

Answer (score -1):

The problem would be the headers with blank space. This could have happened because of copy and paste.

"column_a" != " column_a"